# NuGet 401 auth errors in pipeline

Tags: c#, azure, nuget, azure-pipelines

I have a C# build that is failing intermitently on a failure to connect to an Azure hosted package manager:

```
##[error]#14 2.524 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.426/NuGet.targets(128,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<my_package>/_packaging/***_dotnet/nuget/v3/index.json. [/app/MyProject/MyProject.API/MyProject.API.csproj]
##[error]#14 2.524 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.426/NuGet.targets(128,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [/app/MyProject/MyProject.API/MyProject.API.csproj]
```

One or more re-runs seem to resolve the problem but it isn't clear why it is failing. The pipeline itself is below and the "Reinstall the credential provider even if it already installed" option is selected on the NuGet Authenticate task.

[image: The Pipeline]

What could be the cause for the intermittent failed auth during the image build?

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy Source
COPY NuGet.config ./

COPY ./Commons/ ./Commons
COPY ./MyApp/ ./MyApp

# Restore and publish entry point
WORKDIR ./MyApp/MyApp.API
RUN echo $(ls -lah ../../)
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=nugetconfig \
    dotnet restore --configfile ../../NuGet.config
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/MyApp/MyApp.API/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.API.dll"]
```

Note: The failure is intermittent. Sometimes works first and try and sometimes after many re-runs.

Comment: You've got the NuGetAuthenticate task running after restore, so at the time restore runs, the cred provider hasn't yet been installed. I can't guess how it ever works, but if you authenticate first, then you give it a better chance.

Comment: Is issue due to cookies?  Seen similar issue recently where code wasn't properly handling the cookies.

Comment: @jdweng Cookies in the pipeline? This isn't running in a browser context.

Comment: @zivkan I see what you mean but the one that fails is the one in Docker when it is building the image. The earlier one seems to always work (must have the cred cached)

Comment: Cookies are cookies and are the same in c# and browser.  They are stored in the user stores which is temp space.

Comment: This is a docker build running in a pipeline. The temp stores would be empty and the credential stores would be empty.

Comment: You didn't post your docker file, so your question doesn't have sufficient information to answer. The point of docker and containers is for containers to be isolated, so the CI agent having credentials doesn't mean anything, since the docker container is supposed to be isolated. How are you copying the token to the container? Are you installed the cred provider? Did you read the docs? the cred provider has docs specifically about containers: https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider#docker-containers

Comment: Added Dockerfile